# Removing values after particular character from rdd in scala

Tags: scala

I have following input:

```
(A,123#3A,B,C,D,134#wer,E,242#wer)
```

Is there a way to to get following output using filter/replace/trim or any other function.

```
(A,123,B,C,D,134,E,242)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear.

If you mean that your input is a list of strings then you can do:

```
val input = Seq("A","123#3A","B","C","D","134#wer","E","242#wer")

input.map(_.split("#").head)
```

but if you mean that your input it one string then you can do:

```
val input2 = "(A,123#3A,B,C,D,134#wer,E,242#wer)"

val Pattern = "\\(([a-zA-Z\\d,#]*)\\)".r
input2 match {
  case Pattern(str) => "(" + str.split(",").map(_.split("#").head).mkString(",") + ")"
}
```

Comment: For the single string solution I think this is simpler: `input2.replaceAll("#[^,)]*","")`

Comment: @jwvh that's much simpler, feel free to edit the answer with it

Comment: Its a flatMap RDD.